# How to display custom block in product_list_toolbar?

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, custom

I have a problem with displaing my custom block in `toolbar toolbar-products` between `sorter` and `toolbar-amount`. 
I tried this code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoriesSiblings" name="categoriessiblings" template="Vendor_Module::categoriessiblings.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock >
```

in my `catalog_category_view.xml` but nothing shows.
I can display this block without problems in:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
</referenceContainer>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: please attach screen shot where you need to display custom block ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace you code with following

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar"template="Vendor_Module::categoriessiblings.phtml"/>
```

You have to add default toolbar.phtml code into your custom template and also you can add your custom element in this template

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a way to do this only with .xml file?

Comment: Then you need to override the catalog_category_view.xml in you custom module and modify referenceBlock "product_list_toolbar" with your custom template instead of toolbar.phtml.

Comment: I did it, but it does not work.

Comment: Check my updated answer